# Pushing data back upstream from thread

Tags: rust

I'm completely open to any and all critiques. I'm completely new to multi-threading and the docs don't make much sense to me.

The code provided is min-reproducible. The matrix I'm using is much more elaborate, but this works. The point is to use a global process for various vectors within the structs concurrently, then push all the data upstream and back into the global.

I'm receiving an error at line 59 the first `unwrap()`. Is there a better way to approach this problem altogether???

```
use std::{
    sync::mpsc::channel,
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Data {
    block: Vec<List>,
}
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct List {
    multiplier: f64,
    num: f64,
}

static mut IterationData: Data = Data { block: Vec::new() };

const N: u128 = 100;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        for n in 0..N {
            let mut number = 0.0;

            let list = List {
                multiplier: n as f64,
                num: 1.0,
            };

            IterationData.block.push(list);
        }

        let mut data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(IterationData.clone()));
        let (tx, rx) = channel();
        for n in 0..IterationData.block.len() {
            let (data, tx) = (Arc::clone(&data), tx.clone());
            thread::spawn(move || {
                let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();

                let mut data_2 = Arc::new(Mutex::new(IterationData.block[n].clone()));
                let (t, r) = channel();
                for m in 0..IterationData.block.len() {
                    let (data_2, t) = (Arc::clone(&data_2), t.clone());
                    thread::spawn(move || {
                        let mut data_2 = data_2.lock().unwrap();

                        data_2.num += N as f64;

                        if m + 1 == IterationData.block.len() {
                            t.send(()).unwrap();
                        }
                    });
                }

                r.recv().unwrap();

                let test_2 = Arc::try_unwrap(data_2).unwrap().into_inner().unwrap();

                data.block[n] = test_2;

                if n + 1 == IterationData.block.len() {
                    tx.send(()).unwrap();
                }
            });
        }

        rx.recv().unwrap();

        let test_1 = Arc::try_unwrap(data).unwrap().into_inner().unwrap();

        IterationData = test_1;
    }
}
```

Comment: By assigning the threads to a variable then calling `.join().unwrap()` on each I solved the issue... though I dont understand it.. :/

Comment: It does not appear the `.join` allows the threads to run concurrently... any suggestions?

Comment: If you call `join` immediately, then yes it will prevent the threads from running concurently since you will be waiting for each thread to finish before you start the next one. Instead collect all the thread handles in a `Vec`, then loop over that `Vec` and call `join` on each handle. That way you will have `spawn`ed all the threads before waiting for the first one.

Comment: @Jmb How would you suggest I spin up all threads at once and allow the OS to handle them? I need all 1000 threads running at once. In reality I need 20 but the structure of the code is just as written above. I need to create 5 super threads with 4 sub threads each and they all need to run at once.

Comment: Im not seeing any advantage with all this. If I use a single thread the cycle time is the same as in multi-threading...

Comment: Note that your threads are locking a mutex for the whole duration that they're running, which prevents the other threads from running at the same time. Note that (1) locking is only required if a thread changes data, not if all threads only read data (so your `data_2` doesn't need it), (2) if your threads spend most of their time reading and only write rarely, you can use [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html) to allow the reads to run in parallel, and (3) some algorithms simply can't be parallelized.